# Defining Dentalstatus as a class in python

Tags: python, class

As I am new to coding I have a fundamental question for defining a class for a dental status of a patient. I want to define a class which represents the dental status of a patient (who has 32 teeth). Every tooth can have a different status (e.g. 'h' = 'healthy', 'd' = decayed). The tooth is defined by its position (18, 17, 17 ... 11, 21, 22 ... and so on). The dental status has also two options (existing and treatmentplan). I wonder how to define the class correctly. I am thinking of defining the class with the default teeth-positions and status as a dictionary and create different instances for the patient. Currently I am thinking about the structure:

```
class Dentalstatus:
    '''defines the dental status of a patient'''

    status = {
        '18': 'h',
        .
        .
        .
        '48': 'h',
    }
```

Is it necessary to define the dictionary elements as an attribute of the class or would you rather inherit a single attribute of the status from a dictionary like:

```
status = {
    '18': 'h',
    .
    .
    .
    '48': 'h',
}

class Dentalstatus:
    def __init__(self, status):
        self.status = status
```

Comment: You don't want to use a global dictionary for the status. Then every patient will use the same dictionary.

Comment: Understood. But is it necessary, to initialize every tooth-position itself or can I refer to an instance dictionary?

Comment: Isn't each instance the status of the whole mouth?

Comment: `Dentalstatus` is the status of a patient. The patient has 32 teeth, so they need their own dictionary with all 32 values.

Comment: Actually when I think about it, it might be better if the class would be the patient. Every Patient can have an existing dental status and a status for the planned treatment. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Ok. But can I define the status as a single dictionary?

Comment: Can you give me some example?

Answer (score 1):

I may have gone way too far on the basics here. But this would be what I would go for. I am truly sorry for not finding a better way to deal with the problem of the patient's teeth being a big dictionary.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional

teeth = {
    18: 'd',
    17: 'c',
    16: 'c',
    15: 'c',
    14: 'h',
    13: 'd',
    12: 'c',
    11: 'h',
}


dental_catalog = {
    'c': 'crown',
    'h': 'healthy',
    'd': 'decayed'
}


@dataclass
class Patient:
    name: Optional[str]
    id: int
    dental_health: dict
    health_plan: str
    exists: bool

    def __post_init__(self):
        new_dental_health = {}
        for key, value in teeth.items():
            new_dental_health[key] = dental_catalog[value]
        self.dental_health = new_dental_health


patient_one = Patient(name='John', id=1, dental_health=teeth, health_plan='A', exists=True)
print(patient_one.dental_health)
```

This prints

```
{18: 'decayed', 17: 'crown', 16: 'crown', 15: 'crown', 14: 'healthy', 13: 'decayed', 12: 'crown', 11: 'healthy'}
```

Comment: Actually there are more options than healthy and decayed, e.g. filled, crown, missing...

Comment: also the numbers are not sequentially, they go like 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 38 37 36 35 34 33 32 31 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48. For that i think a list will not be suitable. And yes it is a bit of work to insert the dental status of a patient.

Comment: @tool_77 I tried to be more straightforward on the answer this time, given that your question is about suggestions on what can be done. Unfortunately, on the part of making it easier for you to put the data of the dental health of the patient, it will rely a lot on how you are getting this data. If it is a manual process, I really can't think of simple ways of automatizing it. Nevertheless, I put some design ideas into the answer now, to maybe help you see other angles, based on the comment history of the question.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think it helps a lot!